# vim syntax highlight for change of pattern

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am trying to write a syntax file (.vim) to hightlight in 2 colour format whenever timestamp at the beginning of the line changes.
For example:

```
1:00 - start
1:00 - wait for event
2:00 - wait for event
3:00 - wait for event
3:00 - wait timedout
```

I want to highlight first two line in grey colour, and switch to which when time change from 1:00 to 2:00 for line 3, and change back to grey at 3:00 for  line 4 and 5.
Any one got an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: I have an idea, give me a few minutes to try it out first...

Comment: What do you want it to do if you have multiple events at time 2:00?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with: `\v^(\S+).*\n(\1@!&\zs.*)`

1. `\v` sets the expression to very magic (`:help /magic`)
2. `^` anchors the expression to the beginning of a line
3. `(\S+)` is the first word of the line, we will later compare to this
4. `.*\n` the rest of the line including line break; we don't really care about this
5. `\1@!` matches an empty string here if `\1` would not match (`\1` is the first word of the previous line)
6. `&\zs.*` `&` match this if what comes before (anything other than `\1`) matches, `\zs` ignore what we matched before, this is where the *real* match starts, `.*` match the rest of the line, meaning the entire line, because we only matched "" with `\1@!` and `&` goes back to the starting position anyway*.

So, what this ends up doing is match a whole line if it starts with a different word than the preceding line. If you want to filter a bit more, and, say, only want lines with a time `\d+:\d+` at the start, just switch out the `\S+` for your (more specific) pattern.

Finally, as for highlighting those lines, you can use `:match` (`:help :match` and `:help group-name`) like so: `:match Todo /\v^(\S+).*\n(\1@!&\zs.*)/`. I am using `Todo` here because I like doing that for generic highlights, but you could also use `Underlined` for something less in-your-face, or `Error` for something even more important-looking. The end result would ultimately be the same though.

*meaning, for example, `/..:..&00/` matches 00:00 because both `/00/` and `..:..` match 00:00, but it doesn't match 11:1100, because while `..:..` matches 11:11, `00` goes back again and tries matching at the same place `..:..` did, not after it.

Comment: Looks like you've got an extra `)` at the end of your regexp?

Comment: @Rich True, it's fixed now :)